# What does tilde by itself mean in Lua?

Tags: lua

For the code example:

> num_1 = 12 ~ 36

What is the tilde doing in this example? Is it just a shortened way to represent ~= ?

Comment: You don't have to ask people for trivial stuff like this. Lua has a manual, Open it and search `~`

Answer (score 5):

`˜` is bitwise exclusive OR. See [Bitwise Operators](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.2) in the [Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/).

Answer (score 5):

> What does tilde by itself mean in Lua?

Operators on their own have no meaning. Only in combination with their operands they make sense.

There are three use-cases for `~` in Lua.

[Relational operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.5) `~=`  unequal:  `a ~= b` is true if a is unequal b

[Bitwise operators](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.2)

1. binary `~` bitwise XOR:   `a ~ b` resolves to a number where every bit is the XORed value of `a`'s and `b`'s respective bit
2. unary `~` bitwise NOT:   `~a` resolves to a number where every bit is inverted. So zeros become ones and ones become zeros.

In your case `num_1 = 12 ~ 36` where `~` is used as a binary operator it is the bitwise XOR.

```
100100  36
001100  12
------ 
101000  40
```

So `num_1 = 12 ~ 36` assigns `40` to `num_1`.

Comment: @Joseph thanks for the edit. I must have had a stroke. Shame on me.